# Trying to group by a value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called TESTTABLE

The table script and some sample date

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(
   NODE            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,EVENTID         CHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,TYPE            INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FIRSTOCCURRENCE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,LASTOCCURRENCE  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,TALLY           INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TICKETNUMBER    VARCHAR(20)
  ,TIME_DELTA      VARCHAR(5)
);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Washington','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 23:24','12/13/2017 23:24',1,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('San Diego','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 23:23','12/13/2017 23:23',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Richmond','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 14:23','12/13/2017 14:23',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Richmond','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 23:23','12/13/2017 23:23',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('New York','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 23:24','12/13/2017 23:24',1,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('New York','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 11:32','12/13/2017 11:33',2,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('New York','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 16:35','12/13/2017 16:35',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Landsdown','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 23:24','12/13/2017 23:24',1,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Houston','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 14:24','12/13/2017 14:24',1,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Houston','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 11:31','12/13/2017 11:32',2,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Dallas','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 23:23','12/13/2017 23:23',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Dallas','ReachabilityProblem',2,'12/13/2017 23:24','12/13/2017 23:24',1,NULL,'1 sec');
INSERT INTO Test_Table(NODE,EVENTID,TYPE,FIRSTOCCURRENCE,LASTOCCURRENCE,TALLY,TICKETNUMBER,TIME_DELTA) VALUES ('Coco Beach','ReachabilityProblem',1,'12/13/2017 23:23','12/13/2017 23:23',1,NULL,NULL);
```

I'm trying to obtain this
[image]

I have tried this
Select DATEDIFF(Day, GETDATE(), DATEADD(HOUR, 15, GETDATE()))

```
Select
 [NODE]
 ,[EVENTID]
 ,[TYPE]
 ,[FIRSTOCCURRENCE]
 ,LASTOCCURRENCE]
 ,DATEDIFF(Minute, FIrst OCCURENCE, LAST OCCURENCE) as [Outage in MIN]
 ,[TicketNumber]
 ,[Severity]
 ,Tally]

  From
  [XYZ].[XYZ].[XYZ_STATUS]
  Where 
  [FIRST OCCURRENCE] >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())

  Group by node;
```

Please help a rookie

Comment: `I want the query to group by node`...and what should your query do with the rest of the columns?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide the sample data and expected result. Your select statement is incorrect, there should be comma with each column name. Please correct it.

Comment: Mittal - I'm very new to SQL and trying to learn as I go. If I knew what was wrong with my statement, I would correct it

Comment: -Lamak the rest of the query should list the data based on the fields I listed. I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: There seem to be several people in this thread trying to help you. But we can't read your mind and you are not providing any details about what you want to do. Help us help you by giving us some information.

Comment: Sean - I added  more to the question to try and explain better

Comment: That is not even remotely helpful. It is just a datadump with no clarity on what is what. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Maybe all you need is to add an order by to your query? Totally random guesses at this point.

Comment: How can this topic get an upvote? And some usefull posts get downvotes? Please provide sample data. You just have provided a simple select statement with some date functions. What do you really want?

Comment: I have edited the post. Please let me know if that is easier to understand

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, I assumed this was what you wanted to obtain.

Comment: Your sample data is not valid. You have defined NODE as the primary key but there are multiple rows with that value. I suspect that you don't really want the primary key here? Also, your desired output does not match the sample data. In your output you have OUTAGE MINUTES which I think must correlate to the column TIME_DELTA? Can you explain that data because '1 sec' is rather strange here.

Answer (score 2):

> Group by returns a relation/table with a row for each group, if you are going to use the GROUP BY clause, so in your SELECT statement you can only select the column that you are grouping by and use aggregate functions on that column because the other columns will not appear in the resulting table.

Maybe this is what you want...

```
Select 
DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 15, GETDATE())),
 ,Node
 ,EventID
 ,Type
 ,Severity
 ,Tally
      FROM xyz.xyz.xyz_status
GROUP BY Node,EventID,Type,Severity,Tally
```

> When we group by two or more columns, it is saying "Group them so that all of those with the same col1 and col2 are in the same group, and then calculate all the aggregate functions (Count, Sum, Average, etc.) for each of those groups"

---

Maybe you want this...

```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,(SELECT TOP(1) FIRSTOCCURRENCE FROM 
         xyz.xyz.xyz_status),(SELECT TOP(1) LASTOCCURRENCE FROM 
                                                      xyz.xyz.xyz_status))
    FROM xyz.xyz.xyz_status
      WHERE node = 'Houston';
```

*[**Here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) you can take a look at more examples of **DATEDIFF** function.*

Comment: T-Dejan, this worked.I also need to calculate the difference between the first occurrence timestamp for Houston and the last occurrence timestamp on the second Houston entry. Is that possible?

Comment: I edited the answer, I am not sure if this is what you want, you can try and adjust the code by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should put you on track although Writing reports in SQL is probably a bad idea. What I believe you're wanting to do it output. You can also look at the `ROLLUP` options some of which are deprecated.

```
with data as (
    select
        NODE, EVENTID, TYPE, FIRSTOCCURRENCE, LASTOCCURRENCE,
        DATEDIFF(Minute, FIRSTOCCURRENCE, LASTOCCURRENCE) as OutageInMin,
        TicketNumber, Tally,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NODE ORDER BY FIRSTOCCURRENCE) as rn
    from Test_Table
    --WHERE FIRSTOCCURRENCE >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
)
select
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then 'SITE TOTAL' else NODE end as NODE,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(EVENTID) end as EVENTID,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(TYPE) end as TYPE,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(FIRSTOCCURRENCE) end as FIRSTOCCURRENCE,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(LASTOCCURRENCE) end as LASTOCCURRENCE,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(Tally) end as Tally,
    case when grouping(rn) = 1 then null else min(TicketNumber) end as TicketNumber,
    case when grouping(node) = 1
        then min(OutageInMin) else sum(OutageInMin) end as "Outage In MIN"
from
  data
group by grouping sets ( (NODE, rn), (NODE) )
order by data.NODE, grouping(rn), rn;
```

http://rextester.com/DZIHJ81264

Answer (score -1):

GROUP BY is only authorized in SQL when you are aggregating something. The easiest exemple is a count.

Example : you want to know how much EventID are linked to a given Node :

```
SELECT Count(EventId), node FROM xyz.xyz.xyz_status GROUP BY node;
```

Here is a [site](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) that present the Group By function. If you clarify what you are searching for, we'll give you a more concrete example.

Comment: I mean, it's not strictly necessary to aggregate something to use `GROUP BY`

Comment: Stating you get an error is useless. Providing the message of the error provides some information.

Comment: Just in case this is the reason, I edited the post to add the ; my sample lacked...

Comment: Thank you Heratom for the useful feedback. The sample worked.

Comment: No problem. If you have a more detailed use-case, please let us know, or accept the answer ;)

Comment: @JarJArB, next time you only want two columns as your result, post that in you question so people like me don't waste time trying help with something you didn't really even want in the first place.